# Subdomain not linking with folder

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

The subdomain is working and connecting to my website but linking to the root and no the folder I thought I was linking to.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend
ServerName www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk
<Directory /var/www/html/backend>
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have checked the file structure and the file is located here
 `file:///var/www/html/backend`

Comment: So what actually happens? BTW, you don't have a valid DNS record for that hostname.

Comment: It just links to the website which is located at joshhornby.co.uk I added the DNS a few hours ago maybe it is still filtering through? Here is a print screen http://cl.ly/image/061z2B2j2l0V

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have *two* problems here.

The first problem is that the hostname you referenced in your `ServerName` doesn't exist in the DNS. A different hostname does exist, though...

```
$ host joshhornby.co.uk
joshhornby.co.uk has address 141.101.116.48
joshhornby.co.uk has address 141.101.117.48
$ host teach.joshhornby.co.uk
teach.joshhornby.co.uk has address 192.30.32.208
$ host www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk
Host www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

The second problem is that you specified a different hostname in the `ServerName` field than you are using in your web browser. While Apache is expecting `www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk`, you are using `teach.joshhornby.co.uk`. Since Apache doesn't know what to do with those, it punts, and you get your default virtual host.

To resolve the issue:

1. Add a DNS record for `www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk`.
2. Add `ServerAlias teach.joshhornby.co.uk` to your virtual host.

Comment: My DNS http://cl.ly/image/3T021G081J12 As you can see I have a DNS record for www.teach.joshhornby.co.uk It's shortening the names for some reason but I am guessing they are there And my virtual host file http://cl.ly/image/3L1F04422W0x

Comment: Yuu have those set up _now_. You didn't when you posted the question. Now that you've made the fixes, have you (1) reloaded Apache, and (2) flushed your cache on CloudFlare?

Comment: Oh right! Sorry my mistake. Yes I have reloaded Apache by running apachectl -k graceful and flushed the cache, as you can see nothing loads on teach.joshhornby.co.uk

Comment: I think you should bypass CloudFlare for all of these subdomains until you get this resolved. The "Learning HTML & CSS" shows up for `www.johnhornby.co.uk` but not for any of the other three.

Comment: How odd. I have done as said and bypassed CloudFlare for the subdomains. Is this normal or should It be working now? Could it be down to me incorrectly linking the a folder on the server?

Comment: There's obviously something wrong that I can't see. But you can!